# Android: how to do automatic image center-crop to a specific size after photo taking

Tags: android, crop, photo

i'm having issue doing image center crop to a specific size after taking a still photo by calling MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.

Action Image Capture currently stores the image to image directory, how do i crop image automatically according to my pre-set size and save it to the same path and filename?

appreciate if can give some guidance. im new to android

i do have the URI of the image, just wondering if there's any way to center crop, resize to a specific size eg: 456x456 and save the image to the same URI by overwriting.

below is my code under MainActivity:

```
package com.example.android_take_photos_and_save_gallery;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int CAMERA_PERM_CODE = 101;
    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 102;
    ImageView selectedImage;
    Button cameraBtn;
    String currentPhotoPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        selectedImage = findViewById(R.id.displayImageView);
        cameraBtn = findViewById(R.id.cameraBtn);

        // Open Camera
        cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                verifyPermissions();
            }
        });
    }

    private void verifyPermissions(){
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                permissions[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                permissions[2]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    CAMERA_PERM_CODE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_PERM_CODE){
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission is Required to Use camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
                selectedImage.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(f));
                Log.d("tag", "ABsolute Url of Image is " + Uri.fromFile(f));

                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            }

        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
//        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Android studio is the IDE, your question refers to Android or android java. Also it may help you get good answers if you add some extra tags about the specifics android topics that you are dealing with.

Comment: I believe what you want to do is achievable with android canvas but im not 100% sure as i haven't done it myself. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas